# Why adding Categories does not auto refresh in Backend while using my custom theme?

Tags: categories, theme-development, admin, wp-admin, admin-menu

If I am using my own created custom theme, the Post Categories Page in admin panel is not getting updated automatically when I add a new Category. **To see the new category I have to reload the page Manually**.

When I change to default themes it works as perfectly. So the problem is in my theme.

I think I must have missed something in my functions file.

Any idea what it can be??

Comment: No one has faced this problem??

Comment: I also facing this error. Any solution for this case? @rafsuntaskin

Comment: Check your Function.php file for unwanted spaces from top or bottom. Or may be some Function declaration is not proper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are facing this problem you should check your themes function.php file. I had some error in that which caused this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Locate in your theme's `functions.php` when you add JavaScript scripts.

```
function theme_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'theme-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/app.js', array(), '20170325', true );


  if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
  }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts' );
```

And put them at the end of the file `functions.php`

I have worked doing this action.