# Adding new Category does not refresh the backoffice

Tags: functions, categories

I've already checked [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141830/why-adding-categories-does-not-auto-refresh-in-backend-while-using-my-custom-the) thread from a while back and it said that it might be related to an error in the `functions.php` file.
My code editor does not alert me to any type of error right now
My `functions.php` consists of a mix of different functions right now :

```php
remove_action('wp_head', 'rsd_link');
  remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_generator');
  remove_action('wp_head', 'feed_links', 2);
  remove_action('wp_head', 'index_rel_link');
  remove_action('wp_head', 'wlwmanifest_link');
  remove_action('wp_head', 'feed_links_extra', 3);
  remove_action('wp_head', 'start_post_rel_link', 10, 0);
  remove_action('wp_head', 'parent_post_rel_link', 10, 0);
  remove_action('wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link', 10, 0);
```

```php
function wordpress_setup()
  {

    add_theme_support('title-tag');

    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');

    add_theme_support('custom-logo', array(
      'height' => 160,
      'width' => 160,
    ));

    register_nav_menus(array(
      'Main' => 'Header Menu',
      'Secondary' => 'Secondary Menu',
    ));

  }

  add_action('after_setup_theme','wordpress_setup');
```

```php
  function imo_scripts()
  {
    wp_enqueue_style('fonts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/fonts/Raleway/raleway.css', false, '', 'all'); //font
    wp_enqueue_style('fonts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/fonts/Roboto/roboto.css', false, '', 'all'); //font
    wp_enqueue_style('fonts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/fonts/HelveticaNeue/helveticaneue.css', false, '', 'all'); //font
    wp_enqueue_script('navbar', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/navbar.js'); //script
    wp_enqueue_script('select', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/selectStyle.js'); //script
    wp_enqueue_script('anime', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/anime.min.js'); //library

  }
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'imo_scripts' );
  define('WP_SCSS_ALWAYS_RECOMPILE', true);
```

```php
//* Shortcode : [copyright_year] 
add_shortcode( 'imo_year' , 'add_birth_year' ); 
function add_birth_year() { 
    $birthYear = intval(date(("Y"))-1946);
    return "$birthYear"; 
}
```

I tried to clean the browser cache and it didnt work...
I use `wp super cache` and `page ninja`, should i disable it?

Comment: There's nothing in that code that would cause the error you're experiencing. Try deactivating plugins and switching themes to see if the error eventually stops. When it does, whatever the last thing you deactivated was is likely the culprit.

Comment: Maybe..I'll try to deactivate page ninja and super cache! Thanks anyway!

Comment: I was loading my scripts on the top of my `functions.php` ! i moved them to the end and it fixed it for me!!!